# Does Dreamweaver support automatic code collapsing/folding?

Tags: visual-studio, dreamweaver

In Visual Studio, I can collapse sections of code with arrows in the left gutter. Is there any way to do that in Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Dreamweaver doesn't use code folding by default, but you should get a good idea of how to get that to work from http://forums.adobe.com/thread/226001

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone else that sees this, this is built into Dreamweaver now.

Comment: Can I collapse a function without highlighting it first? This is easily done in notepad++, so I am surprised its not in Dreamweaver cs6. Feel free to correct me and show me how if I am wrong pls.